# Document without a View in Document/View MFC c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, mfc, mdi, document-view

I am creating an application in C++ with Visual Studio 2012 and using the Document/View architecture.

I want to create a project structure like Visual Studio. For those who have not used Visual Studio or not clear on what I'm talking about, I'll give a brief overview:

Users using my program are able to edit "pages", draw on them, etc. When saving, each page is saved into a separate file. At the start, users should be able to create a "project" file. It will be empty at the start. Users will add pages to the project as he/she is working on it. When opening, users should be able to choose the project file to open, which will open all of his/her pages. Different types of pages can be included in one project.

I've got the part of different pages working. I added multiple documents to the DocTemplate. So when users click "New", he/she is able to choose from the different types of pages to create.

I'm not sure on how to create the "project" document. Do I have to add it to the DocTemplate like what I did for others? In that case, it always create a View for me which I don't need. I tried to create a file directly in my MainFrame and read/write to that, but then I lose the nice functionality of having the framework manage my documents. For example, I can't have the users choose to open that file in the Open File dialog. I will have to create workarounds like have a special button to open project files.

I realize this is more of a concept problem. How should I integrate this "project" file into Doc/View framework?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK it should be possible to lieave the View-Class empty (NULL/nullptr).
It is not needed to have it in the Doctemplate.

To get support on the open dialogs you Need to have it in the doc templates.

But maybe it would be better to have your own management of your project... when you open a new project may be other files should close... or open automatically. Is still don't understand how the separate parts are related to the "project".

But I think you must have something that manages the project. The solution explorer is also a view for a project in VS...